# ASP.net VB Calendar

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, web, calendar

I am trying to follow the tutorial from the following link in my asp.net vb application

http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/how_to_start.html#step4initialization

I am on the initilization section and I have no idea where I am supposed to put this code

```js
scheduler.init('scheduler_here', new Date(),"month");
```

Does it go im my html? VB? JS? If it goes in js, which file, and where?

Comment: JavaScript, client-side.

Comment: I have never delt with java script before, and I apologize for my lack of understanding. Is there a specific file, is there a file I need to make, do I embed script in my asp.net page? If so what would my code look like? Thanks

Comment: I think it goes in your JavaScript file, the one mentioned earlier on at the start of the lesson.   ../scheduler/dhtmlxscheduler.js